# Windows 2000 can't connect to SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014

We have an old workstation running Windows 2000 that must connect to MSSQL14 running on Windows server 2012 R2.
When i try to create an ODBC using:

- sa
- TCP/IP (ex. 123.456.789.012)
- not dynamic port 1434 (the one we use on every other workstation successful)

it gives me this error:

> Impossible to connect
>
> SQLState: '01000'
>
> Sql server error: 1006 Impossible to connect
>
> SQLState: '08001'
>
> Sql Server error: 17

I think it's driver fault, but I can't find something useful...
On the workstation there is this driver: Sql Server driver 2000.80.194.00

We need to change this workstation, but I need to make it works ASAP until that moment.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):</sub>*

I would try installing the SQL Server 2005 Native Client in the [Feature Pack for Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - April 2006](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17943).

Please note also that post says *Windows 2000 Service Pack 4* is required to be supported.